# Can't save Geolocation field

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, geolocation

Thank you for the help.  I was unable to find the source of the error and don't have time to troubleshoot it thoroughly so I've proceeded in a different direction and am abandoning this question.

I have added a geolocation field to a SharePoint 2016 list, but am unable to save an entry when I attempt to specify data in this field.  A message appears beneath it stating "A required component for using a geolocation field is not installed.  Either go to the list settings page to delete this field or contact your administrator."  I do not get a correlation id and I can't find anything in the SharePoint logs that appears to relate to this error.  I have three machines in my SharePoint farm (1 FE and 2 App) and have installed SQLSysClrTypes.msi on each machine and did an IISReset on each machine and still receive the same error.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to configure the location and map features for SharePoint. For example, the geolocation column uses Bing Maps so you will need to set the Bing Maps key at web or farm level. The tasks required for integrating location and map functionality can be found here:

[Integrating location and map functionality in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/integrating-location-and-map-functionality-in-sharepoint#what-can-you-do-with-the-location-and-map-features)

Comment: Unfortunately I've done that as well.

Comment: Is your Bing Maps key valid and working?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried it in a different context and it works perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect you'll need to find the error in the logs. Pretty much everything appears in the ULS, so it will hopefully give you more information. If I don't have a correlation ID, I try to match up the times as best as possible and find the error that way.